# Protractor Allow Notifications Chrome 46

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, notifications, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Chrome just auto-updated to version 46.  I am trying to run my protractor tests but I always get the Allow Notifications pop-up now.  Does anyone know how to get around this?  How I can make it always allow notifications for my tests?

[image]

I found the chrome pref options here:
http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc?view=markup

And tried using profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications and still can't get it to work.  I am not sure of the expected value for that pref though?  Not sure where I can find that.  Does anyone see anything wrong with this:

[image]

Comment: Also, when I tried updating the chrome notification settings to allow all sites to show notifications, when I run my protractor tests - it gets reset back to Ask when a site wants to show notifications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I used in order to get it to work:

[image]

Comment: Where did you find the list of values? I need the value for `block` and `0` isn't working.

Comment: @rfodge How to make it in headless chrome?