# Protractor - disable 'harmful' download message on chrome

Tags: jasmine, protractor, chrome-options

I'm trying to download a file in my test. I've managed to start the download without getting the download prompt. 
the problem now is that I'm getting a warning saying that "This type of file can harm your computer.Do you want to keep...anyway?" and I need to choose 'Discard' or 'Keep'.
I've tried to find chromeOptions for that - unsuccessfully. 
currently using those args:

```
args: ['--disable-popup-blocking="true", --allow-unchecked-dangerous-downloads="true", --disable-download-notification="true"']
```

any ideas?

Comment: Did you got the answer for your question..? I tried with the safe browsing as per chrometoaster answer but it is not working. :(

Answer (score 2):

Took me a day of googling and almost gave up... but i found a solution from [How to disable 'This type of file can harm your computer' pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130774/how-to-disable-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-pop-up?rq=1)

Will post the solution here since it was frikin hard to track it down when using protractor as the keyword

```js
prefs = {
    'safebrowsing' => {
        'enabled' => true,
    }
}
```

oddly enough, you need to "turn on" safe browsing to make the message dissapear

Comment: Where I need to add this piece of code.? I have added in the protractor.conf.js file under `exports.config = {` but it is not working, I have changed your code to `prefs: {'safebrowsing':{'enabled':true}}` like this, but it is not working.

Comment: For anyone reading this now I managed to get this working `chromeOptions: {
                args: ['--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection'],
                prefs: {
                    'safebrowsing': true,
                    downloads: { 'prompt_for_download': false }
                }
            },`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following flags:

- [`--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#safebrowsing-disable-download-protection)
- [`--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist).

Comment: Did you try using 1 or 0 instead of "true" "false"?

Comment: @user2880391 please try the rfodge's suggestion.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, you can also try using a chrome option pref instead of an arg.  It would be like the solution shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265701/protractor-allow-notifications-chrome-46 except you would probably want to try the pref of profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups with a value of 2 (1 is allow and 2 is block).