# How to allow this "Store file on this device" notification of chrome(61) using protractor

Tags: protractor

Whenever I am running my application on chrome using protractor I am getting this notification pop up. How can handle this pop up using protractor. I have tried some methods which is mentioned in below link but still no luck.

[Protractor Allow Notifications Chrome 46](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265701/protractor-allow-notifications-chrome-46)
[image]